# fortran: how to call intrinsic function time() when I already have an array time

Tags: function, time, fortran, naming

I need to time a routine and I want wallclock time, so I am using the time() routine. However, my code already has a 2D array called time, so when I do:
startt=time() it thinks I am referring to the array. How do I get around this without changing my array name?

I tried to make a function outside my main program to bypass this but it doesn't work:

```
     program timetest

     real time(0:10,0:10) ! dummy array to demonstrate problem
     integer*8 startt,endt,tdif

     time=0 ! initialize dummy array to 0

     startt=gettime()
     call sleep(2) !stuff to be timed
     endt=gettime()

     tdif=endt-startt
     print*,"tdif= ",tdif

     end

     integer*8 function gettime()
       gettime=time()
       print*,"gettime= ",gettime
     end function
```

Output:

gettime=                         0

gettime=      -9223372036854775808

tdif=                         0

Comment: My $0.02: use an IDE with syntax highlighting (obviously, one that recognizes Fortran). The highlighting ought to help eliminate any use of a Fortran intrinsic as a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have two different things visible in a program unit by the same name. My first recommendation to you would be to use the Fortran standard intrinsic subroutine SYSTEM_CLOCK rather than time().

The approach you took with a separate routine should work if you declared gettime with the correct datatype in the caller. As you have it, gettime is integer(4) in the main program but integer(8) in the function itself. These need to match.

Comment: Thanks, though I'm not sure I want to use SYSTEM_CLOCK because if I exceed count_max it will mess up my timings. Also, in my main program I added gettime as an integer*8 variable but my output still doesn't make sense:  gettime=                         0
 gettime=      -9223372036854775808
 tdif=      -9223372036854775808

Comment: I just ended up using secnds

Comment: secnds can overflow too - and can have strange behavior if you go past midnight. Given that it is non-standard, different implementations can do different things. The other problem is that TIME() is perhaps not a function in the implementation you are using. In Intel Fortran, it's a subroutine, which explains the results you're getting. This is why I recommended a standard intrinsic.